# setInterval time becomes faster after every cycle

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

Hi I am trying to track the time spent by user on a webpage. So I have written the following javascript to do so.

The script starts tracking the time when the window becomes focused and then pauses if the user moves to some other tab or minimises the window.

[here is the fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/9fzd1dap/)

following is the code:

```
$(function(){
    var count = 0;
    var interval;

    var ispaused=false;
    function setPause(){
        ispaused=true;
    }

    function unpause(){
        ispaused=false;
    }

    $(window).on("blur focus", function(e) {
        var prevType = $(this).data("prevType");

        if (prevType != e.type) {   //  reduce double fire issues
            switch (e.type) {
                case "blur":
                    setPause();
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    break;
                case "focus":
                    unpause();
                    var interval = setInterval(
                        function(){
                            if(!ispaused) {
                                $('#timer').text(count += 1);
                            }
                        },1000
                    );
                    break;
            }
        }

        $(this).data("prevType", e.type);
});

});
```

The timer starts when you focus the area and pauses when you blur out, but the timer becomes faster after every cycle of focus and blur. No idea why that is happening. Please help !

Comment: `clearInterval(interval);` this interval is not the same as this one `var interval = setInterval(` so you're not clearing the correct one. (remove the `var`)

Comment: try replacing `var interval = setInterval(` with `interval = setInterval(`

Comment: @atinder thanks man that worked !

Comment: aelor is correct: by using `var interval = setInterval( ...` instead of `interval = setInterval( ... ` you are declaring a new local variable interval every time and that timer never get stopped by the `clearInterval`

Comment: @zerkms why is atinder's advice terrible ?, that is working for me

Comment: @zerkms i know that it is not the perfect way to do it, but it at least solve his problem.

Comment: @zerkms please enlighten me more on what is wrong and what is right. I am not an expert in javascript as is evident from my code

Comment: @atinder my apologies, I need glasses. I was wrong.

Comment: no worries my friend :)

Comment: @aelor, I had updated my answer brother

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the fiddle you provided and found out that you are storing the interval variable on a local variable i had tried to fix the problem to see if it is working and had updated the fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/9fzd1dap/1/

This is the updated Script

```
    $(function () {
        var count = 0;
        var interval; //This is the global interval variable

        var ispaused = false;
        function setPause() {
            ispaused = true;
        }

        function unpause() {
            ispaused = false;
        }

        $(window).on("blur focus", function (e) {
            var prevType = $(this).data("prevType");

            if (prevType != e.type) {   //  reduce double fire issues
                switch (e.type) {
                    case "blur":
                        setPause();
                        break;
                    case "focus":
                        unpause();
                        clearInterval(interval);
                        //I removed the var keyword from the line below to prevent dual declarations.
                        interval = setInterval(
                            function () {
                                if (!ispaused) {
                                    $('#timer').text(count += 1);
                                }
                            }, 1000
                        );
                        break;
                }
            }

            $(this).data("prevType", e.type);
        });

    });
```

What happened is that the **global interval** variable is not being populated and the **local interval** (inside the function) variable is the one that gets populated. I've already tested it on the updated fiddle and seems to work fine ;)

Comment: I want to do it on the full window, I am trying to find out the average time spent by a user on a page

Comment: and how am I supposed to do that sir ?

Comment: I am afraif sir , it doesnt help, you can try out your edits in the fiddle I have provided in the quetion

Comment: @aelor, please check my updated answer. I think that bubbling is not the problem. It was related to scoping of your interval variable.